# bootstrap carousel: the plugin shows me all image not slideshow

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I using `bootstrap carousel` on my site. The problem in that the plugin shows me all images.
See example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XSywC/3/), please.

The plugin call correctly, because in the Firebug `item` and `active item` is changing.
Where is a problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing the [bootstrap.css](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css) where it has defined many things like

```
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel .item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
     -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
      -ms-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
       -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
          transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
}

.carousel .item > img {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
}

.carousel .active,
.carousel .next,
.carousel .prev {
  display: block;
}

.carousel .active {
  left: 0;
}

.carousel .next,
.carousel .prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel .next {
  left: 100%;
}

.carousel .prev {
  left: -100%;
}

.carousel .next.left,
.carousel .prev.right {
  left: 0;
}

.carousel .active.left {
  left: -100%;
}

.carousel .active.right {
  left: 100%;
}

.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 15px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  background: #222222;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 23px;
     -moz-border-radius: 23px;
          border-radius: 23px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.carousel-control.right {
  right: 15px;
  left: auto;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px 5px;
  background: #333333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.carousel-caption h4,
.carousel-caption p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/nPyKZ/